# Why do answered questions show up in the unanswered questions list?

Tags: discussion

Many of the questions in the [Unanswered](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered) list have one or more answers already. Why is this, and why can't it be changed to only allow unanswered questions into the Unanswered Questions list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the right of the question list there is a count of how many unanswered questions there are. In there it says:

> questions with no upvoted answers

So there may be answers on the questions, but none of the answers are upvoted, so they stay in the queue.

There are no preferences for the unanswered queue specifically.

Comment: Which seems an eminently sensible approach to me. How much can any "answer" merit that designation, if no-one has actually endorsed it with even a single upvote?

Comment: As a person who wastes lots of time in the unanswered questions queue, providing answers that may never merit that designation, I have to say that the votelessness of some answers may have less to do with their quality than with a kind of luck-of-the-draw randomness regarding who sees the question and answer as it drifts back through the pile of current questions. Example: A question I had answered two weeks ago to deafening (and continuous) silence suddenly picked up three upvotes yesterday. The reason: Someone else answered it and gave the question another chance to drift downward.

Comment: It's also possible that people start feeling sorry for older answers if nothing better comes along after a decent interval. And of course one huge factor in the lack of upvotes is that many of the questions are of practically no interest to anyone but the asker. I can't bring myself to attempt answers to some of them—and I have very low standards when it comes to accepting the challenge of answering questions of no real significance. A lot of "unanswered" questions are either so obscure that no one can answer them or so lame that no one cares. Hence, few views and few votes up or down.